# Gradle : How to run tests from a module dependency?

Tags: java, gradle, module, build.gradle

I have modified my project to become multi-platform.

**Previous state:**
Only one module (project) with one build.gradle. All the tests were in the test folder and when I run `gradlew testDebug` all my 500 tests were running.

**New state:**
I have a main gradle project which doesn't do anything but holding 3 modules

- core
- androidversion
- rasberryPiVersion

Each of these modules have it's own gradle file but only android and rasberryPi module can be built. In their dependencies (in their respective build.gradle file), they compile against the "core" module. Like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':clapcore')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android:android:4.1.1.4'
}
```

All my 500 tests are now in the core. So when I do `gradlew clean assembleDebug testDebug` on the Android module, no test is detected and the folder of test-result is empty.

I tried to run the `testDebug` command on the core module directly, but since it doesn't build by itself, I receive the error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'testDebug' not found in project ':core'.
```

So my question is: Is there a way, in gradle, to tell the "testDebug" command to run all the tests that are in it's module dependency (core)?

I have also tried to add a testCompile in the dependency of android module but it doesnt work, like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':clapcore')
    testCompile project(':clapcore')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android:android:4.1.1.4'
}
```

Thanks!

***EDIT***
I have found that I can do the command `gradlew build` on the core and it will run the test in the 'core' module. But I would like a way to run these test by "cascade" if it's possible.

***EDIT 2 ***
I have found that I can do the command `gradlew buildNeeded` on the 'android' module and it will do a build for android module and the core. Unfortunately, it only build in release! If someone can point me a way to use this function but in debug, it would be amazing. I need it in debug because the release build launch many more task like change of the version, commit to git, push, etc... This is only for a nightly build, so it needs to be in debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the documentation of the Gradle website, I discovered that the very nice function `buildNeeded` simply run all buildType and you can't change. The only functions that give you the possibility to choose the buildType are `assembleDebug` and `assembleRelease` respectively.

Since my release process (creation of tag, update of version, push to git, etc..) was running right after `assembleRelease`, I was stuck because running `buildNeeded` in a nightly build would trigger the release process.

So I modified my build.gradle file to create a task called `releaseVersion` which dependsOn `zipalignRelease`. So when I really want to create a release, I call `releaseVersion` but when I simply want to build/test in the nightly build, I call `buildNeeded` command.

Things to watch out: The tests results will be in each of the "build" folder of each module. Take good care to clean all module if you are using CI.